# Passando parametro navigation do stack navigation pra componente filho

Tags: react, react-native, react-navigation

Sou novo em react native e estou construindo um app onde preciso repedir varias vezes o mesmo código com apenas algumas diferenças, então logico que eu estou criando componentes pra isso, porem em um dos componentes tem um botão e quando pressionado ele navegue ate outra rota, geralmente quando preciso fazer isso o stack navigation sempre passa como props a propriedade navigation e usamos da seguinte maneira `navigation.navigate('nome-da-rota')`, porem eu preciso usar essa propriedade dentro do componente filho, porem todas vez que tento isso recebo o erro `ERROR    Warning: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component.`

O meu componente esta em outro arquivo

Meu código:

```
export default function Main({navigation}) {
   return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.touch} onPress={logout}>
          <Image source={Logout} style={styles.logoutImage}></Image>
          <Text style={styles.outText}>Sair</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <ScrollView>
        {admin && <Admin navigation={navigation} />}
      </ScrollView>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: O componente filho já deve ter o `navigation`, já testou não passar e só recuperar?

Comment: Já sim, ele n tem, aliás tentei até criar uma Stack só dele pra ele receber esse parametro, mas ao q parece esse parametro só é passado quando a rota é chamada, n renderizada

Comment: você deu um console.log(props) e não tem?

Comment: Isso eu n tentei, eu costumo desestruturar as props, vou tentar isso pra ver sem desestruturar

Comment: `<Admin navigation={navigation} />`  é que to falando será que precisa passar esse `props`, se poderia retirar e testar também `navigation={navigation}` já que os componentes estão envolvidos pelo navegação

Comment: Há sim entendi Então eu já tentei tirar ele, e recuperar ele no componente ele da undefined pq n consegue achar a props q tô usando, porém ele n funciona pq está num arquivo externo, vou tentar definir meu componente dentro do componente pai, n vai ficar organizado mas se funcionar ótimo kkkk

Comment: ta dificil porque não estou entendendo o cenário

Comment: Deixa eu tentar resumir, eu tô criando um app onde vai ter níveis de acesso, e no main é onde ele verifica se o acesso e redireciona pro componente correspondente, só q esse componente te admin por ex dentro dele existe um painel onde dependendo do botão o usuário clicar ele vai ser redirecionado pra outra página na aplicação, então eu preciso dentro do meu componente admin teria um outro componente Card onde seria chamado várias vezes com rotas diferente, então pra n repetir ele criei um separado porém esse card precisa navegar pra outra rota, aí está o problema

Comment: Esse componente está dentro do Navigation?

Comment: O componente Card está separado em outro arquivo

Comment: Separado tudo bem, eu quero saber se ele está dentro do child (filhos) onde o Pai maior seja Navigation?

Comment: Sim está no caso dentro do meu componente main q é o pai com o navigator passo pro admin q é o filho e dentro do admin passo pro Card TMB

Comment: O navigator é dentro do main ou fora?

Comment: O navigator é passado automático pelo Stack navigator pro main mas eu preciso usar ele dentro do componente q está dentro de admin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### *Hook* `useNavigation`

Uma outra alternativa, além da dada pelo @LucasSouza, é usar o [*hook* `useNavigation`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation). Como [a própria documentação diz](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/connecting-navigation-prop/), ele é mais útil quando você não quer passar a *prop* `navigation` para um componente filho, ou quando você tem uma árvore de componentes muito aninhada, onde você teria que ficar passando a *prop* pra cada componente da árvore, até chegar no ponto onde você quer. Por exemplo:

```
<Main>
  <Header>
    <NavList>
       {/* aqui usa a prop `navigation` */}
       <NavLink />
    </NavList>
  </Header>
</Main>
```

---

Pra usar o *hook*  `useNavigation`, é da mesma forma que os outros *hooks*:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

export default function MyButton() {
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    return (
        <Button
            title="Click me!"
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('MyRoute')}
        />
    );
}
```

Você importa ele e faz a chamada de função.

#### A mensagem de alerta

Outra a coisa a se notar, é que a mensagem de erro:

```
ERROR Warning: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component.
```

Aparece quando você muda um estado de um componente em renderização, a partir de outro componente, conforme [pode se ver na documentação do React](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/blog/2020/02/26/react-v16.13.0.html#warnings-for-some-updates-during-render).

Então, dependendo de como você está fazendo, ou talvez de como o `react-navigation` funciona, o estado de um componente está sendo mudado por outro, de uma forma inapropriada.

Comment: Cara perfeito, eu não fazia ideia que tinha um Hook pra isso separado, e olha que pesquisei hein, mas parece que não o suficiente, muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa pro seu caso seria centralizar no seu componente Main as funções de navegação e descer essas funções via ligação direta, exemplo:

```
export default Main = ({navigation}) => {
    const navegaAdmin = navigation => navigation.navigate('nome-da-rota');
    
    return (
     <>
       <View style={styles.header}>
         <TouchableOpacity style={styles.touch} onPress={logout}>
           <Image source={Logout} style={styles.logoutImage}></Image>
           <Text style={styles.outText}>Sair</Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
       <ScrollView>
         {admin && <Admin navegar={navegaAdmin} />}
       </ScrollView>
     </>
   )
 }
```

E no seu componente Admin no botão ficaria algo assim:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={navegar} />
```

Caso não queira fazer o destructing das props no seu componente Admin então o botão de navegação ficaria assim:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={props.navegar} />
```

Comment: Cara muito obrigado, a sua resposta funcionou mt bem, eu estava fazendo meio certo então né, mas tinha q passar a função toda né ja com o nome da rota.